# Grafana - How to block the user and IP address from brute force login attack

Tags: grafana

I'm using grafana version v9.2.1.

I'm able to hit the server continuously by entering wrong credentials multiple times.

I need to block the IP address and username when three are 3 continuous failure login attempts.

I tried enabling **disable_brute_force_login_protection = false** in **/etc/grafana/grafana.ini**, but grafana didn't block the account nor thrown any Error message like 'Multiple Failure login attempts'.

Can anyone suggest a solution to block IPAddress and Username when 3 continuous failure login attempts

Answer (score 1):

Grafana brute force will block user (not an IP), when there is at least 5 failed attempts in last 5 minutes. This behaviour is not customisable from the config file. You can change [config constants](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/83c101dc34c948978bc8d1e7772c5c519d70a482/pkg/services/loginattempt/loginattemptimpl/login_attempt.go#L14-L15) and compile own Grafana version, which will fit your needs.